# Member Actions - If Statement - Active Admin/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, activeadmin

I have this following situation. In a page, i have a checkbox. if the checkbox is checked it should automatically execute an action,if not checked then do another action.

The actions are represented by member_actions. So i want to do this scenario.

```
if($("#checkbox_name").is(":checked")) {
  then do member_action_1 
 }else {
 do member_action_2
}
```

I'm waiting for your answers and hints !
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

let's first think about this **if condition**, it will be executed on the client side or the server side ?
the checkbox will be in the client side and the action will be on the server
so we want to communicate between them :D
here we want to use something like **ajax** query to send a request to the server to do something
you have to modify your **routes.rb** to direct your request to the target member action